# How do i create a new directory where i could upload a file in java using play framework

Tags: playframework

I am trying to upload a file to my local machine but now i want to ask the user to select a directory or create a new one to save the uploaded file there,any idea how to achieve this in play framework.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to show a directory list from your server to the user?? Seems like a really bad plan. I also do not see any use case where this would be acceptable, why bothering the user where you store it? Just present him the link after you have saved it.

Anyway, you can create directories with Java (if you use Play-Java) no problem:

```
File dir = new File("folderName");
dir.mkdir();
```

If you persist in asking the user in what folder the file should be saved, I would advise you the following:

Create somewhere outside the play project a folder called `uploaded`. Within this folder the user can upload the file into his own folder, just show an input field where the user can enter a 'foldername'.

*Note* that uploaded files in Play are not visible directly after upload, because the image did not exist when Play was starting (in classpath). So the uploaded folder should be managed by Apache or any other server.

**EDIT**
If you want to list all file you can use something like:

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); // folder is created folder

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        // here you can build array of strings (filenames)
        // that can be passed to your view
    }
}
```

And the pass the new string array or `listOfFiles` to your view.

```
return ok(list.render(listOfFiles));
```

Comment: thanks...actually i wanted to display all the uploaded files in a directory in the view page ,any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: thanks,any idea like how to display the time of the file created and also the size?